# Selecting rows with a particular year and month

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe looks like this

```
 2013-12-25 |
 2013-12-25 |
 2013-12-25 |
 2013-12-25 |
 2013-12-25 |
 ....
 ....
 2014-01-01 |
 2014-01-01 |
 2014-01-01 |
 2014-01-01 |
 2014-01-01 |
 2014-01-01 |
 2014-01-01 |
 2014-01-01 |
```

I have to select all the rows with year 2014 and month as 01.

How can I go ahead?

Comment: Are they strings or actual dates? Are they the index, or the first column? Have you read [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html)? What code have you written so far?

Comment: They are Date values .and sadly i couldnot find any help with the documentation.

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991627/selecting-a-subset-of-a-pandas-dataframe-indexed-by-datetimeindex-with-a-list-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably isn't the most Pythonic way but you could just slice on dates.

```
df[(df['datecol'] >= pd.datetime(2014, 1, 1)) & (df['datecol'] <= pd.datetime(2014, 1, 31))]
```

Alternatively you could create a map for the criteria to do boolean selection on month and year.

```
crit1 = df['datecol'].map(lambda x : x.year == 2014)
crit2 = df['datecol'].map(lambda x : x.month == 1)

df[crit1 & crit2]
```

Comment: Thanks, more compact solution:  

```df[df['datecol'].map(lambda x : (x.year == 2014) & (x.month == 1))]```